Remotely using perf in yocto
At my customer, we’re switching from ptxdist to Yocto. At the same time, we’re also switching to a far less powerful processor, so some optimizations are in order. I’m looking for a profiling tool that’s both informative and easy to use, and compatible with Yocto.
I’ve found this page, and I’ve had some success using perf as instructed. In a nutshell, the instructions involve installing debug symbols on the target, and then running perf record and perf report there.
That approach is not without drawbacks

Creating a disk-image with debug symbols takes significantly longer than one without
Flashing an image with debug symbols also takes longer
The target doesn’t actually have enough memory to run perf report, so I had to add a swap-file
Did I mention the target is slow? ;-)

I’m now looking to do “remote profiling”. I.e. similar to “remote debugging”, I want to have the debug symbols on the host only, run perf record on the target and then perf report on the host. On google, I’ve found some hints that that should be possible, but not any instructions on how to do it.
Currently I’m hopelessly stuck. That is to say: perf is not part of the SDK, and there doesn’t seem to be a perf-native or perf-cross package to build. On the other hand, I don’t think the idea is so outlandish that I am the first one to try this.
Any tips?
(Currently using Yocto Langdale, because that seems to be the last one Xilinx released, but I'm happy to take inspiration from anywhere ;-)

What do you mean by "perf is not part of the SDK"? I see Yocto recipe for perf is available https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/recipes-kernel/perf/perf.bb

Near as I can tell, at least on Langdale, that recipe can only be used to build a perf that can run on the target, not on the host.
What I mean is that if you follow the instructions for building, installing and using the SDK, you'll find that it doesn't contain perf.
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/sdk-manual/index.html

Add the following line to your image.bb file TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-perf" Then run populate_sdk and check if the resulting SDK includes the package.

The easy way to check is host.manifest file located in build/tmp-glibc/deploy/sdk/ host.manifest describes the packages populated into the Yocto SDK.

ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'nativesdk-perf'.

You can try to extend the existing perf.bb recipe for it to provide nativesdk-perf https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#nativesdk

As a reference, search for similar recipes by text search with the string BBCLASSEXTEND = "nativesdk"

You can try to extend the existing perf.bb recipe for it to provide nativesdk-perf as explained in docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#nativesdk
As a reference, search for similar recipes by text search with the string BBCLASSEXTEND = "nativesdk"
After you extend perf.bb, add the following line to your image.bb file
TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK += "nativesdk-perf"
Then run

bitbake populate_sdk

and check if the resulting SDK includes the package.
The easy way to check SDK contents is host.manifest file located in build/tmp-glibc/deploy/sdk/host.manifest. It describes the packages populated into the Yocto SDK.
